# Pasting libaacs.so.0 into vlc folder

Tags: permissions

I want to paste a codec "libaacs.so.0" into my "usr\lib\vlc" folder, but every time I do it, I always get "Permission Denied".

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `Alt+F2`, type `gksudo nautilus`; enter your password. Now navigate to `/lib/vlc` and try pasting it.